# How to write files to google bucket using Apache Beam dynamically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to write a few files to google bucket using Apache Beam, but the file location and folder names are generated from first index in the file, so how do I create this dictionary and write my files to it?

```
metadata = (data_from_test |'CSVConversionMeta' >> beam.ParDo(WriteToCSVmeta())|'Writing To File' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://tester1212/CIK/YEAR/FILING/metadata.csv'))
```

So, this is the code where I write the file, but I want the YEAR to get fetched from the csv and create a folder during runtime.

Comment: Is the date is the creation date? or a date inside the CSV that you want to also print in the file name? (That also implies that you create csv file per date). Last question: is the date is known before the pipeline start? Or is it a data known by reading the data inside the pipeline?

Comment: The date is read from the csv, and it is known before the pipeline starts.

Answer (score 1):

If your date is known before the Pipeline start, you can do this

```
year="2020"
metadata = (data_from_test |'CSVConversionMeta' >> beam.ParDo(WriteToCSVmeta())|'Writing To File' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://tester1212/CIK/{}/FILING/metadata.csv'.format(year)))
```